# sed: to merge contents of one CSV to another based on variable match

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Attempting to correlate GEO IP data from one CSV to an access log of another.

Sample lines of data:

**CSV1**

```
Bob,App1,8-Jan-15,8.8.8.8
April,App3,2-Jan-15,5.5.5.5
George,App2,1-Feb-15,8.8.8.8
```

**CSV2**

```
8.8.8.8,US,United States,CA,California,Mountain View,94040,America/Los_Angeles
5.5.5.5,US,United States,FL,Florida,Miami
```

I want to search CSV1 for any IP listed in in CSV2 and append fields 1,2,4 to CSV1 when the IP matches.

So far I have, but I'm getting errors I believe at the SED portion.

```
    #!/bin/bash

for LINE in $( cat CSV2 | awk -F',' '{print $1 "," $2 "," $4}' )
do
        $IP = $( echo $LINE | cut -d, -f1 )
        sed -i.bak "s/"$IP/\""$LINE\"" CSV1
done
```

Desired Output:

```
Bob,App1,8-Jan-15,8.8.8.8,United States,CA
Dawn,App3,2-Jan-15,5.5.5.5,United States,FL
George,App2,1-Feb-15,8.8.8.8,United States,CA
```

Comment: Your desired output is not clear. Please show it.

Comment: fyi, this line is wrong: `$IP = $( echo $LINE | cut -d, -f1 )` -- variable asssignments in bash do not use a `$` on the left-hand side, and you must not have spaces around the `=` -- `IP=$( echo "$LINE" | cut -d, -f1 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `join` command:

```
$ join -t , -1 4 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.3,2.4 <(sort -t, -k4,4 CSV1) <(sort -t, CSV2)
Bob,App1,8-Jan-15,8.8.8.8,United States,CA
```

Using `sort` is overkill here, but for >1 line files, `join` requires the files to be sorted on the join key

With awk

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR == FNR {a[$1] = $3 OFS $4; next} $4 in a {print $0, a[$4]}' CSV2 CSV1
Bob,App1,8-Jan-15,8.8.8.8,United States,CA
```

Comment: I've updated my original question. Sorry for lack of detail.
The awk script provides no output, and join gives me the following error:
join: /dev/fd/62:34: is not sorted:8.8.8.8,US,United States,,,,,,38.00,-97.00,0

Comment: Hmm, both the join and awk commands work for me with your given data.